# Adding keybindings to an JFace popup dialog

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am writing an eclipse plugin.I have a JFace dialog which displays a tree. I want to change the contents to the dialog when user presses a certain combination of keys. Like When we press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> in eclipse it displays the quick outline box and it provides a toggle show Inherited Members when we press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> again.
How can I implement this?

Comment: Are you asking how to add `KeyListener`s to the dialog or how to implement such a "quick outline box"?

Comment: how to add `KeyListener`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [FAQ How do I provide a keyboard shortcut for my action](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action%3F).

Comment: When i visited that link got the following message: There is currently no text in this page, you can search for this page title in other pages or edit this page.

Comment: Update - this is the working link: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action%3F